# Connecting to Azure Event Grid and Service Bus using Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure

I have a scenario where Azure [ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview) sends events to [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) whenever there is a message in Azure Service bus's queue/topic.
So how do I establish the connection in Java/Spring with Event Grid to receive events and also with Service Bus to pull the messages.
What are the configurations are to be done in Java/Spring to establish connections with Event Grid and Azure Service bus? Also what are the configuration that has to be done on the application side(application.yml or properties file) to include things like connection string and etc.?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-eventgrid/1.4.0-beta.1

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu Hi, what are the configuration that has to be done on the application side after including these dependencies, like in the application.yml, say like connection string and so on?

Comment: check Microsoft documentation please, but yeah you will need a connectionString https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-servicebus-readme?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Thank you @JuanmaFeliu. I still couldn't figure out or find any docs on how to connect with Event Grid to listen to its events from java/spring. Like what are the configuration that has to be done apart from including dependencies. It'll be great if you can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be easily achieved by azure function app.

[Set the service bus queue/topic as the trigger of your function to receive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=java#example).

And use Azure SDK for Java to send events to event grid:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/eventgrid/client?view=azure-java-stable

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-eventgrid-readme?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Thank you @BowmanZhu. Azure Function isn't used here and it out of scope in my scenario, Instead in my case Service bus topic is already been chosen as Event Handler for the Event Grid quiet similar to this link(learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-service-bus). So I have two Service bus topics. First topic which has actual data/message and the second topic(event handler associated with Event Grid) has the  the event info emitted by the first topic. So I need to listen to the second topic and then pull the actual data from first topic

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Service Bus to Event Grid integration**

Service Bus can now emit events to Event Grid when there are messages in a queue or a subscription when no receivers are present. You can create Event Grid subscriptions to your Service Bus namespaces, listen to these events, and then react to the events by starting a receiver.

To enable the feature, you need the following items:

- A Service Bus Premium namespace with at least one Service Bus queue or a Service Bus topic with at least one subscription.
- Contributor access to the Service Bus namespace. Navigate to your Service Bus namespace in the Azure portal, and then select Access control (IAM), and select Role assignments tab. Verify that you have the contributor access to the namespace.
- Additionally, you need an Event Grid subscription for the Service Bus namespace. This subscription receives a notification from Event Grid that there are messages to be picked up. Typical subscribers could be the Logic Apps feature of Azure App Service, Azure Functions, or a webhook contacting a web app. The subscriber then processes the messages.

[image]

Check this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept?tabs=event-grid-event-schema) for more info.

Check [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-function#connect-the-function-and-namespace-via-event-grid) to use Azure Function to connect both.

Check this doc to use [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-example#receive-messages-by-using-logic-apps) to connect both.

Azure CLI:

```
namespaceid=$(az resource show --namespace Microsoft.ServiceBus --resource-type namespaces --name "<service bus namespace>" --resource-group "<resource group that contains the service bus namespace>" --query id --output tsv

az eventgrid event-subscription create --resource-id $namespaceid --name "<YOUR EVENT GRID SUBSCRIPTION NAME>" --endpoint "<your_endpoint_url>" --subject-ends-with "<YOUR SERVICE BUS SUBSCRIPTION NAME>"
```

Powershell:

```
$namespaceID = (Get-AzServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroupName "<YOUR RESOURCE GROUP NAME>" -NamespaceName "<YOUR NAMESPACE NAME>").Id

New-AzEVentGridSubscription -EventSubscriptionName "<YOUR EVENT GRID SUBSCRIPTION NAME>" -ResourceId $namespaceID -Endpoint "<YOUR ENDPOINT URL>” -SubjectEndsWith "<YOUR SERVICE BUS SUBSCRIPTION NAME>"
```